# Spring Security: how to authenicate WebSocket with zoneinfo

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Can someone please advise how to secure a web socket endpoint using Spring Security framework?

I have an application secured with Spring Security.
One of the endpoints is a web socket.
Inside the web socket handler I need to authenticate a user making a connection to the web socket.
Specifically, I need to acquire both userid and also zone/tenant id.

If I use tag **sec:http** for websocket endpoint in spring-security.xml (please see the file below), this does trigger a login, and then  inside web socket's **@onOpen(Session session)** handler 
when I invoke **session.getUserPrincipal()**, the returned principal has a correct username inside it.

However I also need zone/tenant-id information.

I am trying to use **SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()** which should contain it, but the call returns null.
Apparently, **sec:http** does not cause Authentication object to be created for web socket requests.

I had been referred to

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/websocket.html

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-websocket-security

that seems to advise that to get an authenticator with zone information in it for a websocket endpoint, I need to add the following section to spring-security.xml:

```
<sec:websocket-message-broker>
    <sec:intercept-message pattern="/WebSocket.svc" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</sec:websocket-message-broker>
```

Yet, when I add it and trying to start the application it fails with the following traceback/message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Security namespace does not support decoration of element [websocket-message-broker]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.reportUnsupportedNodeType(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:144) ~[spring-security-config-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
```

I am using Spring Security 4.1.2, and 4.3.1 for master Spring.

It is also unclear from Spring documentation whether **sec:websocket-message-broker** and **sec:http** should be used in conjunction for the web socket endpoint or are mutually exclusive.

Thanks for advice.

Sergey

P.S. My spring-security.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

    <sec:http pattern="/Consumer.svc/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        use-expressions="true">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/Consumer.svc/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:http pattern="/WebSocket.svc" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        use-expressions="true">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/WebSocket.svc" access="isAuthenticated()"  />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:websocket-message-broker>
        <sec:intercept-message pattern="/WebSocket.svc" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </sec:websocket-message-broker>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                    <property name="expressionHandler" ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"  />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="offlineTokenServices" />

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <!-- ... also some other elements here ... -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to add the following to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this to spring-security.xml:

```
<bean id="springSecurityMessagePathMatcher"    
class="org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher"/>
```

Now Spring does not throw an exception at startup and parses spring-security.xml fine, but it does not work either. **SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()** still returns null.